# distorted display while and after installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, display

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04. I am getting distorted display, while installing Ubuntu as well as after installation. The file check before installation had no error. So, I proceeded with installation with distorted display, hoping it will be solved after installation but it persists.

I have tried the solution as provided in the fuzzy display for intel graphics card `sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel` but it is not working.
I have additional Nvidia Geforce graphics card to which my VGA cable is connected.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, i'm running in same issue ... did you resolved it somehow ? thx

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this precise issue as well (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Ryzen 5950X w/128GB on MSI B550 gaming board). All available kernel/OS and BIOS updates applied to no effect. This machine is for number crunching, not graphics, so to get it going I grabbed an old low-end card out of my surplus (low-end by modern standards; Quadro FX 560).

Disabling the nouveau driver and then rebooting brings the machine up in vanilla low-res graphical mode, which is likely enough for this machine. An attempt was made to install Nvidia's driver (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/123709/en-us) but it reported inconsistencies in the paths to modprobe.  Both `/usr/sbin/modprobe` and `/sbin/modprobe` are links to `/bin/kmod`.  However, `/proc/sys/kernel/modprobe` says `/sbin/modprobe` while `which modprobe` reports `/usr/sbin/modprobe`. While it got past this, the installation then couldn't make new kernel modules, etc... FYI.

Comment: I've spliced your previous answer into this one to give context... it looks like you've made some progress which can serve as a partial answer here. However, if you're posting to seek help, please ask a new question rather than posting in answers (you can link to an existing question if it's relevant). This is a Q&A site - check out our [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) :)